# Query regarding overlay view not working on Settings

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile, appsettings

I had created an application which draws an overlay view on top when user opens any application in android device. But I found that this overlay view stays on any application user opened but this overlay disappears when user opens settings in Samsung mobile having Android 10,11,12,13,14. Is there any particular criteria/permission(user or system) which can be added to the code, so that this overlay can be displayed even when user opens Settings or any other application. Please guide here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

I tried android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW with below code, but this overlay disappears when user opens settings:

```
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    overlayView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.overlay_layout, null);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            200,
            200,
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ?
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY :
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );
```